# Where is the download link for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to download the standard version of PostgreSQL (for Windows) for a while now. It seems like each and every link I try points my towards EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL plus.

Here are the links that I've tried.

[The PostgreSQL Windows Download page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows) redirects to [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload), which also requires an account signup, which I did.

I clicked on the Windows x86-32 icon which brought me to [this page](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts). It apparently asks me to select a platform group. There is a big arrow to the side. Clicking on the Windows link that the arrow is point to brings me to two [PostgreSQL plus](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/windows) tutorials.

Clicking [the platform group](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/menu-group/choose-platform-group) link at the top brings me to a blank page.

I don't know what to say here. It really seems like their throwing up a lot of roadblocks and *encouraging* me to pick the easy to download PostgreSQL plus. at a price of course.

I have to say that I'm a little unimpressed with the high friction download experience. Can anyone help me out with a download link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you arrive on the "Thank you" page, see the following sentence: "Your download should begin shortly. If it does not, please click on this link to download the file."

click the link

http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.0.4-1-windows_x64.exe

Comment: Believe it or not, that "Your download should begin shortly. If it does not, please click on this link to download the file." text isn't visible (both Opera and IE).

Comment: I believe it's happening to you, but both Opera 11 and IE 7 work fine for me here.

Answer (score 1):

`"The PostgreSQL Windows Download page redirects to EnterpriseDB, which also requires an account signup, which I did."`

You don't need to register. For me, after some seconds a save dialog comes. Check if you have popup-blocker stoppping somethings or try to change your browser

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register, Just click on the appropriate link http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows

Also make sure your popup block is disabled.